# RxJava retry when other observable emits error

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I wanna create chain of request But it should looks that.

I call `apiService.changePassword()` and I can get success 200 and 401 error. If I get success then all is fine else I have to call `apiService.refreshToken()` and now If I get refreshed token I should call again `apiService.changePassword()`. I think about using `retryWhen`. What I should use?

[Edit:]

I got solution:

```
apiService.jobOffers(...)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap(new Func1<Response<ResponseBody>, Observable<FeedDataProvider>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<FeedDataProvider> call(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        ...

                    }
                }).retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> observable) {
                        return observable.flatMap(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Observable<?> call(Throwable throwable) {
                                if(throwable instanceof RetrofitException) {
                                    ///refresh token
                                    }
                                }
                                return Observable.error(throwable);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Yes, that's the perfect use case for `retryWhen`.

Comment: But How? :D Do you have kind of example?